# How to implement a notifications on my webpages while any data insertion or updation occured on my custom tables

Tags: notifications

How to implement a notifications on my web pages while any data insertion or updation occured on my custom tables.

My requirement is for an auction website where once an user places a bid, then all the  other logged in users in that region should get the notifications.

Comment: For this you can implement https://www.drupal.org/project/nodejs

Comment: I have tried to implement the notifications using nodejs referring the Node.js integration documentation from https://www.drupal.org/node/1713530 But I couldn't find the notification popup on submitting the System-wide Broadcast Notification example from the link dmin/config/nodejs/nodejs_notify/broadcast.

Answer (score 0):

You need to accomplish with three module and [rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules), [private message](https://www.drupal.org/project/privatemsg) and [custom](http://dominiquedecooman.com/blog/drupal-custom-rules-how-write-your-own-events-conditions-actions-and-custom-object-custom-token) module.

rules provide event, condition and action through which you need to set, events supports CRUD. Condition provides you to check condition has been fulfill and Event sends you private message to groups or personal mail / text message.

Private message provides you send bulk message / mail through rules. Message itself can be thread.Private message has feature to count unread message to particular user.

Custom module to create event, conditions and actions for rules to custom table.